# Why getting 404 when try to get page via react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I get 404 when try to get by url `/items/best`. Why it could happens? I use react-router-dom

```
 <Router history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/items" component={Items} />
                        <Route exact path="/items/best" component={BestItems} />
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Redirect from="*" to="/login" />
                    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Comment: Which 404 page are you seeing? Have you deployed the code to a server?

Comment: No, I haven't deployed this code. It's just webpack devserver. I get 404 Not found when go to /items/best . No redirect happens and of course I can't get my BestItems component. Getting just /items works well

Comment: @Tatiana Can you please check this https://codesandbox.io/embed/hidden-leaf-lkpbb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Christiaan Now I see if remove second / in my route and try get by /itemsbest then it works. But I need second /

Comment: @DhananiYatish Oh, i see it works in sandbox

Comment: Seems like it's a problem with webpack, because if I use nginx all works as well

Comment: Thanks everybody! It resoved by adding one more setting in webpack config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally adding follow setting in webpack config helped me:

```
output: {
    publicPath: "/",
},
```